# Sencha Touch success callback from JSONP proxy?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am just learning sencha touch. I am trying to retrieve data form a server (following the getting started example). I am trying to print the response to the console in a success callback. Here is the code I am attempting to use, but nothing is being printed to the console.

```
proxy: {
  type: 'jsonp',
  url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
  reader: {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
  },
  listeners: {
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    }
}
```

so, what is the proper syntax for a success callback so that I can do some stuff with the response like print it in the console?

Thanks!

Comment: try changing `success: function(response)` to `callback: function(success,response)`. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
```

for this:

```
root: 'responseData.feed.entries'
```

Or could you change `proxy: {type: 'jsonp' ... }` for `proxy: {type: 'ajax' ... }` plus above.

I hope these helps.

Comment: he wants to listen to an event (or smt similar) when the request is completed, not simply how to config the `proxy`